# Google+ Domains API via service account fails with 403 Forbidden

Tags: ruby, google-api-ruby-client, google-domain-api

I have a simple Ruby code that I combined from several examples. It uses Google+ Domain API. I followed all steps to authorize a service account (https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation), but my requests fail with 403 Forbidden:

```
{"error"=>{"errors"=>[
{"domain"=>"global", "reason"=>"forbidden", "message"=>"Forbidden"}], 
"code"=>403, "message"=>"Forbidden"}}
```

The same queries work fine if I execute them using Google APIs Explorer console. I think it's related to the service account vs. user account authentication. What did I miss?

The full code is here https://github.com/admitriyev/propellant/blob/master/main.rb

[edited] I added an installed app flow into the same code, and it worked fine (full code is on Gihub above). I still don't know what I missed in the service flow though.

Comment: Which authentication and authorization mechanism did you choose for Google APIs ?

for e.g. if you chose Google’s OAuth scheme for this you should obtain an authentication token first

Comment: @cvibha I don't fully understand your question. It's OAuth2 with service account and domain delegation. It did not work. However, I just modified it to use the installed app flow, and it worked fine.

Comment: Here is a [link](http://arailstechie.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/now-you-can-have-better-youtube-integration-with-ruby-on-rails/) to a third party service using Google API

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was missing the email of the actual domain user on behalf of whom it should be authorized. I also switched to use Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter which is a cleaner
abstraction:

```
client_asserter = Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter.new(
  config['client_email'],
  PLUS_LOGIN_SCOPE,
  key
)
$client.authorization = client_asserter.authorize(config['user_email'])
```

My full example is here: https://github.com/admitriyev/propellant/blob/master/main.rb